# EXM 3.5 Redirect Url rootPath

Tags: exm

I'm using the EXM 3.5

On the Email campaign I have configured the sitecore content with a page which redirects, after a user clicks on the link which was sent by EXM through email, which looks something like this : http://mysite.com/sitecore%20modules/Web/EXM/RedirectUrlPage.aspx?ec_eq=SYpG5fgYN92bK9NA66tfH7G7Jg71orn8uhLYUa%...

After the redirect a 404 page error is thrown, because it is redirecting to a full path of the content.

eg: Blog -> CD -> Website -> Home **http://mysite.com/blog/cd/website/home**

But I wanted the redirecte only to the **/home** item.

Any ideas?

Comment: Hi, did you manage to resolve this issue? I am facing same issue

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that EXM is not able to correctly resolve the site that it's supposed to be resolving. EXM utilizes Sitecore's LinkManager/LinkProvider for creating a URL based on an item. It appears that Link Manager is not able to determine which site to use, and therefore using the full item path to create the URL.

For starters, I would make sure that the Message Root is inside of the Start Item Path for the site that it's supposed to resolve.

Secondly, I would inspect the `<modifyHyperlink>` pipeline. This is the pipeline that transforms the URL coming out of the EXM message to the encrypted URL that you posted. Adding a debugging processor at parts of this pipeline can help determine what Sitecore is doing to the link. Which, in turn, if you need to modify this at all, you can implement a processor here to ensure that the link is created correctly.

Do note that all links in an EXM message go through this pipeline, so keep any changes to a minimum to ensure that processing time is not impacted during dispatches.

Answer (score 0):

EXM is sending emails from the CM server and sometimes people don't create proper  configs for the CM sites. You need to make sure a CM site resolves to the site `/blog/cd/website/home` in the  config and that you have a mapping for CM to CD url in an item under `/sitecore/system/Settings/Email/System/Hostname Mappings` node.

Emails are NOT sent from the CD servers where all the site mappings are perfect.